# Android app not responding when closed

Tags: android, surfaceview, forceclose

I am working on an game for android, and when I close the app it crashes. I think this is because I am doing a render with a null canvas. When I do a null check, the program doesn't crash, but it doesn't reopen after it has been closed. Here is my thread's run:

```
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas;
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");

    long beginTime;     // the time when the cycle begun
    long timeDiff;      // the time it took for the cycle to execute
    int sleepTime;      // ms to sleep (<0 if we're behind)
    int framesSkipped;  // number of frames being skipped 

    sleepTime = 0;

    while (running) {
        canvas = null;
        // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing
        // in the surface
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                framesSkipped = 0;  // resetting the frames skipped
                // update game state 
                this.gamePanel.update();
                // render state to the screen
                // draws the canvas on the panel
                this.gamePanel.render(canvas);              
                // calculate how long did the cycle take
                timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
                // calculate sleep time
                sleepTime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                if (sleepTime > 0) {
                    // if sleepTime > 0 we're OK
                    try {
                        // send the thread to sleep for a short period
                        // very useful for battery saving
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);    
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }

                while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
                    // we need to catch up
                    this.gamePanel.update(); // update without rendering
                    sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD;  // add frame period to check if in next frame
                    framesSkipped++;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            // in case of an exception the surface is not left in 
            // an inconsistent state
            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }   // end finally
    }
}
```

and here are the relavent methods in the surface class.

```
    @Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // at this point the surface is created and
    // we can safely start the game loop
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Surface is being destroyed");
    // tell the thread to shut down and wait for it to finish
    // this is a clean shutdown
    boolean retry = true;
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.setRunning(false);
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // try again shutting down the thread
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Thread was shut down cleanly");
}
```

Is the null check correct and I am just missing the methods to resume the activity?

Logcat when nullcheck isn't in place:

```
03-01 10:37:19.557: E/AndroidRuntime(25129): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-16380
03-01 10:37:19.557: E/AndroidRuntime(25129): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 10:37:19.557: E/AndroidRuntime(25129):    at org.awesome.AndroidGame.MainGamePanel.render(MainGamePanel.java:192)
03-01 10:37:19.557: E/AndroidRuntime(25129):    at org.awesome.AndroidGame.MainThread.run(MainThread.java:73)
03-01 10:37:23.357: E/BitmapFactory(25280): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /level_1_1.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-01 10:37:36.097: E/AndroidRuntime(25280): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-16395
03-01 10:37:36.097: E/AndroidRuntime(25280): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 10:37:36.097: E/AndroidRuntime(25280):    at org.awesome.AndroidGame.MainGamePanel.render(MainGamePanel.java:192)
03-01 10:37:36.097: E/AndroidRuntime(25280):    at org.awesome.AndroidGame.MainThread.run(MainThread.java:73)
03-01 11:02:49.227: E/AndroidRuntime(26150): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-16425
03-01 11:02:49.227: E/AndroidRuntime(26150): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 11:02:49.227: E/AndroidRuntime(26150):    at org.awesome.AndroidGame.MainGamePanel.render(MainGamePanel.java:192)
03-01 11:02:49.227: E/AndroidRuntime(26150):    at org.awesome.AndroidGame.MainThread.run(MainThread.java:73)
03-01 11:02:53.717: E/AndroidRuntime(26177): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-16428
03-01 11:02:53.717: E/AndroidRuntime(26177): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 11:02:53.717: E/AndroidRuntime(26177):    at org.awesome.AndroidGame.MainGamePanel.render(MainGamePanel.java:192)
03-01 11:02:53.717: E/AndroidRuntime(26177):    at org.awesome.AndroidGame.MainThread.run(MainThread.java:73)
```

Logcat when nullcheck is in place:

```
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1045)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at org.awesome.AndroidGame.MainGamePanel.surfaceCreated(MainGamePanel.java:83)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:569)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:231)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:7537)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1039)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1039)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1039)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1211)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-01 11:58:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32292):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: When you say "close the app",  do you mean hit the back button, hit the home button, or did provide custom exit functionality in your code?

Comment: Both buttons crash my app, but I was talking specifically about the home button.

Comment: Does the stacktrace from LogCat point to a specific line of code?

Comment: Yes, the render call in thread

Comment: What exception is raised? Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Sure, it's a NullPointer (canvas I was thinking)

Comment: Add the **full** StackTrace/LogCat.

Comment: I think that is from multiple crashes though

Comment: @Brandon  What error/exception do you get when you put the null check like you said, and cannot open the app?  Can you trace to the problem?

Comment: There is more than one problem here I think... I have been using thread.join in surfacedestroyed thus far. But that logcat is when I am using thread.setRunning(false) which allows me to press back and get back to the app no problem, but when I try to re-open after going home it crahes.

Comment: Thread.start() is where logcat is showing the exception.  Try putting that in a try/catch to avoid the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start your thread I believe you should check it see if it already exists.

It's my understanding that you can't re-start a thread in Android, so you should check to see if it existed previously and if it did, start a new one like so:

```
if(thread.getState()==Thread.State.TERMINATED){            //Exists?        
 thread = new Thread(holder, context, handler);}           //Re-Create

thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
```

As for the null canvas, if you mean the check against null in your run method (main w'hile loop), in the 'finally' section before you unlockandpost, yes this is correct.

However I have a feeling you didn't mean this check.  I had a similar problem when if I pressed the back key, for some reason, a Null Canvas was being intermittenty passed to my onDraw/Render method.  I actually had to encase my entire code in that method inside a check against null canvas so it would only render if check came back negative!  It worked  and was perfectly stable after that.

If I remember correctly, after lots of research on the internet, it appears this is an issue a few people have had.